# How to specify named instance as constructor parameter for type that are auto-registered for StructureMap

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap, auto-registration

Using StructureMap, We have all types that are auto registered.

```
public class MessageRegistry : Registry
{
    public MessageRegistry(){
        Scan(x =>
             {
                 x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof (FormatHelper));
                 x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof (IMessage<>));
             });
    }
}
```

So, in case we look for `IMessage<Currency>`, it will find below type:

```
CurrencyMessageHandler : IMessage<Currency>
{
    public CurrencyMessageHandler(ISession instance) 
}
```

As to the constructor parameter type ISession, we like it to be auto wired, however, we have got more than 1 implementation like SqlSession and OracleSession. In this case, we would like to pass SqlSession as constructor parameter.

How to specify named instance as constructor parameter in this case?

Much appreciated.

Comment: In my experience, it's best to avoid this sort of constructs, because that always complicates your code and your DI configuration. Can you explain a bit more what that `CustomeType` is used for, how it is used, where it comes from, and how it might change over the application's lifetime?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know it is not a good design. I can actually refactor codes to avoid it. However, i am just wondering is it possible to achieve the goal without refactoring? (Update the question above. :) )

Comment: So when do you use `SqlSession` and when `OracleSession`? Does your application simultaniously connect to two databases? Do they both have their own data model or do they represent the same model?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem and I solved it by excluding the type from the scan and then custom configuring it:

```
Scan(scan => scan.Exclude(t => t == typeof(CurrencyMessageHandler));
```

and then:

```
For<IMessage<Currency>>.Add<CurrencyMessageHandler>()
     .Ctor<ISession>.Is(a => a.TheInstanceNamed("SqlServer"));
```